# Upgrade custom SSIS Tasks from 2008 R2 to 2012

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have several custom SSIS Tasks and Components implemented for SQL Server 2008 R2. Now we want to switch to SQL Server 2012. First I tried just to open my DTSX packages in VS 2010 and no package could be loaded. Does anybody knows what I have to change in my projects that I can use my tasks and components with SQL Server 2012.

Thanks

Comment: Is Visual Studio prompting you to upgrade your packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've installed SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server Data Tools, you should be prompted to upgrade your solution when you open it. I'm also assuming your 2008R2 assemblies are setup for signing.

After going thru the upgrade wizard you need to do several things:

1. Change your custom tasks and components to target the .NET 4
   Framework in each of the project properties, in the Application Tab,
   under Target framework.
2. Update the assembly references in each of your projects to point to
   the appropriate SqlServer dlls.
3. Build and copy your project dlls to the appropriate directory,
   depending on what kind of components you are updating, i.e. `Program
   Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\PiplelineComponents`
   `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Tasks`
4. Register your components in the GAC.
5. Close Visual Studio and then reopen; open your SSIS packages and
   refresh the SSIS Toolbox, by right clicking in the tool box and
   selected `Refresh Toolbox`.

You can get more detailed info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345161.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was missing step 2.

Comment: One thing...if your packages do not validate after your upgrade, you may need to delete the old component from your package and then drag and drop a new one to replace it.